# How to replace numbers next to specific strings in a text file with new numbers, in C++?

Tags: string, c++11, replace, find, file-handling

I have a text file which contains certain lines of text (combination of words, spaces, special characters and integers).

**An example representation of the text file would be**:

```
   <in line8> the quick brown fox) 8)
   <in line15> lazy dog jumps over) 7)
   <in line22> jumps over quick brown) 13)
```

I would like to find and replace numbers that are next to unique strings with new numbers.

To be very precise, I would like to replace the number *8* next to the string *fox)* in the first line with a new number.

Likewise the number *7* next to the string *over)* in the second line with a new number, etc.

The non-numerical elements of the text (words, spaces and special characters before the number) should be left undisturbed while we replace the numbers

The code I tried so far is below:

```
int main()
{
    string strReplace = "the quick brown fox) 8)"; //Original string
    string strNew = "the quick brown fox) 13)"; //Replaced string
    ifstream filein("input.txt"); //File to read from
    ofstream fileout("output.txt"); //Temporary file
    if(!filein || !fileout)
    {
        cout << "Error opening files!" << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    string strTemp;
    //bool found = false;
    while(filein >> strTemp)
    {
        if(strTemp == strReplace){
            strTemp = strNew;
            //found = true;
        }
        strTemp += "\n";
        fileout << strTemp;
        //if(found) break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I know this can be easily achieved in a language like Python. But in C++ it seems quite tricky. Can anyone assist ?

Comment: Could you show us your code? What have you tried?

Comment: Sure. Please give me a moment so that I can pullout only the relevant section of code.

Comment: Dear @sg7. I have update my question with the code I tried so far in accordance to your request.

Comment: `filein >> strTemp` reads one word (whitespace-delimited sequence of characters) at a time. You probably want to read one line at a time, as in `while (getline(filein, strTemp)) {...}`